# Spring JSP Redirection

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to redirect to a another jsp page.in Spring MVC But I get HTTP Status 404 - /registration.jsp error.all i want to do is to open page. register new person page or add new product page from the home page

the path or project hierarchy: [image: project hierarchy]
I dont want to use JSTL or tag's. What is the best way to do this?

I tried this on my JSP page:

```
<ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none"> <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/grcon?path=register">User Registartion</a>
</li>
<li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/grcon?path=usermang">User Management</></li></ul>
```

And my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/grcon/{path}" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getGrcon(@PathParam(value = "path") String path)
    {
        ModelAndView modegeron = null;
        if (path != null && path.equals("register")) {
           modegeron = new ModelAndView("registeruser");
        } else if (path != null && path.equals("usermang"))
                {
           modegeron = new ModelAndView("manageuser");
        } else {
           modegeron = new ModelAndView("index");
        }
        return modegeron;
    }
}
```

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="recon.controller" />

<!-- viewResolver tell which viewResolver to use it tell the location of 
        the view in the project -->

  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
 </bean>

  <mvc:resources location="/resoures/**" mapping="/resoures/"/>
  <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
  <mvc:annotation-driven/>
 </beans>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <session-config>
        <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>
```

HTTP Message

```
HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'path' is not present

type Status report

message Required String parameter 'path' is not present

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.67
```

Comment: try to post dispather xml and web.xml

Comment: in your href you have placed the URL as `/System/{path}` but in your Controller you have mapped the one method you shared at `/grcon/{path}` ,  is this the method that you want to be invoked?

Comment: @AntJavaDev yes it is the same method

Comment: ok then try to correct the URL either in your controller or in your .jsp and then test it again

Comment: also could you post the exception in your server logs , it should be something like `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI .....`

Comment: well if thats the error then as @ekem chitsiga suggests below , your annotation is not correct , change it to `@RequestParam("path")` and edit your controller , also check this tutorial [here](http://www.journaldev.com/3358/spring-mvc-requestmapping-annotation-example-with-controller-methods-headers-params-requestparam-pathvariable)  , it shows both examples with RequestParam and PathVariable annotations

Comment: @AntJavaDev you have seen my anntation which part is not correct ?

Comment: in your controller you are requesting a path regex or identifier something like : grcon/User23/Page23 , but in your jsp you are passing a url variable with the ?path identifier. so you if you want to capture that variable in your controller you should write your method like : `@RequestMapping(value ="/grcon" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getGrcon(@RequestParam(value = "path") String path)
    { `

Comment: @AntJavaDev all i want to do is to open page. register new person page or add new product page from the home page

Comment: check the tutorial that i sent you above  , it shows both examples with RequestParam and PathVariable annotations with the correct usage

Comment: @AntJavai get the controller part how to i get it to work in JSP

Comment: just change the controller with the snippet i posted , dont change anything in the jsp . In case it still throws exception , please post the new log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots for reading i notice i was not doing the right thing the below code work for me

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/register" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getRegister()
    {

        ModelAndView modelregister = new ModelAndView();

        modelregister.setViewName("registeruser");
        modelregister.addObject("Registration", "info");

        return modelregister;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/manageuser" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getManageUser()
    {

        ModelAndView modelManageUser = new ModelAndView();

        modelManageUser.setViewName("manageuser");
        modelManageUser.addObject("User Records", "records");

        return modelManageUser;

    }
```

JSP

```
<ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
 <li><a href="register">User Registration</a></li>
 <li><a href="manageuser">User Management</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either pick request parameters or url template variables in your controller or jsp.To use url template variables replace @PathParam(value="path") with @PathVariable(value = "path").

In your jsp replace the link url with 
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/grcon/register and href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/grcon/usermang

To use request parameters replace @PathParam(value = "path") with @RequestParam(value = "path"). Then mantain your jsp url links as they already use request parameters

NB. The PathParam annoation is not part of Spring MVC. Its a JAX-RS annotation for use with JEE standard

Comment: after replacing  @PathParam(value="path") with @PathVariable(value = "path"). it redirect me to the index page but the address path (http://localhost:8080/G_Rcon_Servlet/grcon/registeruser=register) why do i get the wrong page